# How to modify an user permissions for a specific channel nextcord

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

I want to create a channel where just me and who wrote the command can send messages.
So far i have this code:

```
@commands.command()
    async def ticket(self, ctx, title, context):
        guild = ctx.guild
        member = ctx.author.name
        role = ctx.author.id
        category = guild.get_channel(1175421519439073380)
        channel = await category.create_text_channel(f'{member}-ticket')
        channel_id = channel.id
        getch = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
        if getch:
            embed = nextcord.Embed(
                title=title,
                description="<@&1146194171422572644> and <@696415634359189516> \n" + context,
                color=nextcord.Colour.green()
            )
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I dont know how to make just me and the user to see the channel.

Comment: You must add user to this channel, then user can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be late, but maybe you still need this.

Do `channel_id.set_permissions(member, permission=TrueOrFalse)`

You can find a list of permissions here: [permissions](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#permissions)